# Suggestions with making for loop go once on python

Tags: python

```
lowercase = {"abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz": 5}
uppercase = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ": 6}
word = input("What is your word?")
score = 0
for x in word:
    countforboth = 0
for y in lowercase:
    if x in y:  # if the word has a lower case letter
        score = score + lowercase[y]
for z in uppercase:
    if x in z:
        score = score + uppercase[z]
countforboth = 0
for y in lowercase:
    for z in uppercase:
        if x in z and y:
            countforboth = countforboth + 1  # if the word has both lower case and upper case lett
            score = score + 7

if countforboth > 1:
    score -= 7 * (countforboth - 1)
    print("Your score is", score)
elif countforboth < 2:
    print("Your score is", score)
```

For this string checker - to have 7 added on to the score if there is a least one capital letter among a lower case letter or vice versa, not for **every** capital among lower case or vice versa. How can I achieve this? Even with this added code, when I put in "HellO" score comes on as 41 instead of 34

Answer (score 1):

Once you detect a uppercase better, you could simply `break` out of the loop. So:

```
password = "HelloWorld"
score = 0

for letter in password:
    if letter.isupper():
        score += 7
        break

print(score) # score = 7
```

Alternatively, set a flag:

```
password = "HelloWorld"
found_upper_case = False
score = 0

for letter in password:
    if not found_upper_case and letter.isupper():
        score += 7
        found_upper_case = True
    # check for symbols or whatever

print(score) # score = 7
```

Comment: if you read their logic at the end it's more complicated than that I think. (not saying you should implement that request tho)

Comment: I'm just addressing the problem of having multiple capitals count, their final counting logic is entirely up to them.

Comment: I don't think that's possible as if I type in "HellO" the first letter will only be counted and not the rest. Am I making sense??

Comment: Check for uppercases in another loop, or set a flag to indicate that you've found a uppercase and shouldn't bother trying to find another.